# Вызов из фрагмента метода активности

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня активность содержит фрагмент. При нажатии кнопки в этом фрагменте, у меня должны измениться состояния View в макете активности. В активности у меня есть готовый метод, который будет делать это. Но как мне это реализовать, чтобы при нажатии по этой кнопки, вызывался бы метод активности?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объявляешь интерфейс с методами которые тебе необходимо выполнять в
Activity:

```
interface FragmentActions {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Имплементируешь интерфейс в Activity:

```
class MainActivity extend Activity implement FragmentActions {
        override void doSomething(){
          ... Вызываешь свои методы реализованные в активности
        }
    }
```

Вызываешь метод во фрагменте:

```
class MainFragment extend Fragment {
    private FragmentActions listener;
    override void onAttach(Context context){
      super.onAttach(context)
      listener = (FragmentActions)context;
    }
    override void onViewCreated(...){
      btn.setOnClickListener(()->listener.doSomething())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Это можно сделать через интерфейс (назовем MyCallback). Создаете интерфейс с названием вашего метода (можно внутри вашего фрагмента).

```
public interface MyCallback{
    void method();
}
```

Вашу активити наследуете от этого интерфейса.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyCallback {

    @ovveride
    public void method(){
    //логика
    }
}
```

В фрагменте создаете объект данного типа и делаете

```
@Override
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private  MyCallback myCallback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    myCallback = (MyCallback) context;
}
}
```

Ну и вызовите метод `myCallback.method()` где вам надо во фрагмете